# std::string a container

Tags: c++, containers

Is std::string a container class in standard c++ library, restricted to hold only char elements?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a typedef of `std::basic_string<char>`, actually. `std::basic_string` is a container class specifically designed for string operations. This container can be used for wide characters (`wchar_t`) as well; for that case its typedef would be `wstring`.

Answer (score 5):

A `std::basic_string<>` is a class that is very much like a sequence container.  Note that `std::basic_string` can contain **any** POD type, not just elements of type `char` (which is what a `std::string` is) or `wchar_t` (`std::wstring`).

I believe that a `basic_string` supports all the operations of a sequence container.  However, note that by definition a container type can hold any assignable and copy-constructable types - not just POD types.  So a `basic_string` is very much like a container, but strictly speaking it's not a container.

In other words there are types that can be used with a container that cannot be used with a `basic_string`.  But for those types that can be used with a `basic_string`, the `std::basic_string` provides the full interface of a sequence container (I think) plus additional functionality.

Comment: Michael, please correct in if I'm wrong. Your answer seems contradictory with these statements. 
- Note that std::basic_string can contain any POD type, not just elements of type char.
- there are types that can be used with a container that cannot be used with a basic_string.
So the questions now is whether std::basic_string can hold any type, primitive or otherwise. If yes, only then std::basic_string behaves like a true STL container.

Comment: @Ankur - I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. `basic_string<>`  cannot hold non-POD types which a container like `vector<>` could hold.  But for POD types (like a plain-old struct) you can have a `std::basic_string<mystruct_t>`.  To be honest, I'm just going by what the standard says - it looks like after a bit of experimentation, some compilers (GCC 3.4.5 and Comeau) will accept at least simple non-POD types as a type used for `basic_string<>` and some compilers won't accept a simple aggregate POD type (Digital Mars, VC6).  VC9 behaves as the standard seems to call for.

Comment: @Michael. Okay, I think I got it now. BTW, what does POD type mean. Does it mean primitive data types(such as int, char) or more?

Comment: @Anku: Plain Old Data - a C++98 concept that indicates simple types. POD types cannot have virtual functions, and can be safely memcpy'd, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

std::string as a typedef for `basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >` is pretty much limited to the **char** type.

However, I don't think basic_string itself is necessarily limited to only character types (though, as the name suggests, it might be intended to be used for string data).

```
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    std::basic_string<int> numbers_1, numbers_2;
    numbers_1 += 1;
    numbers_2 += 2;
    std::basic_string<int> numbers_3 = numbers_1 + numbers_2 + 3;
    unsigned pos = numbers_3.find(10);
    assert(pos == std::basic_string<int>::npos);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

std::string is a  basic_string.
It's not necessarily a char, but it has to follow the char traits
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/char_traits/

Comment: No, `std::string` is a `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >`, which is absolutely restricted to `char`.